# When I send an textarea via ajax with this: "??????????????" I get on server side: jQuery20305394186528865248_139(...)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I send an textarea via ajax with this:

> "??????????????????"

He gets me on the server side as:

> jQuery20305394186528865248_1398553714562?????????????????????

My JS code:

```
        var text_feed = $("textarea[name='text_feed']").val(); // ok
        var Data = JSON.stringify({text_feed: text_feed});
        console.log(Data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: 'data=' + Data,
            url: '/ajax/AddComment',
            dataType: 'json',

            beforeSend: function() {
               .. ETC ..                
            },
            success: function(retorno) {
                .. ETC ..
            },
            error: function(a, b, error) {
                .. ETC ..
            },
            complete: function() {
               .. ETC ..
            }
```

Server Side Code:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], TRUE);
$text_feed = $data['text_feed'];
```

I believe that there should be a function to encode my text, but I do not know =/

Thanks for all.

Comment: Why do you encode the params to json prior the send? Just pass it as normal POST param

Comment: Yes, but I have other values ​​that I hid now to enhance visualization of the question

Comment: That's a function name that jQuery automatically generated, usually used with JSONP. I'm surprised jQuery replaces ? In the dats though.

Comment: Still no reason for encoding the data. Pass the data as JavaScript object directly to the `data` property of the Ajax call

Comment: OK, i'll pass to post method and test!

Comment: I changed and the problem continues

Comment: Resolved!! Later I'll post the solution, i am go now to bed hehe